# is it possible to write nginx modules in java?

Tags: java, nginx

I would like to use nginx as a high end web server, from my small research it looks like its performance and workload is superior to others.
My main programming language is java.  is it possible then to write nginx modules in java?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, I think it's only C....
You could read more [here](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html)

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to write "modules"?  Why so?

Maybe all you need is put your Java web service behind the nginx?

Comment: I thought about that but wondered if the overhead would be too big.  I need the service to be super fast...

Answer (score 2):

With [nginx-clojure](http://nginx-clojure.github.io) we can  write content handler,rewrite handler, access handler and header filter in java, clojure or groovy.